# Java 11 HttpCookie.parse throws IllegalArgumentException when parsing cookies that contain JSON

Tags: java, http, cookies

I have an application runs for more than a year and does something what looks like scraping websites. Now I want to set the cookies that a website returns in their header but since a couple of days it looks like the `HttpCookie.parse()` method can't parse cookies that contain JSON.

It is so strange that I don't think it can be true but maybe you had this before?

Here is an example:

```
your_cookie_name={"key":"value","key2":"value2"}; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

Java does the following thing:

```
1. HttpCookie.parse("your_cookie_name={"key":"value","key2":"value2"}; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly")
```

Then:

```
2. HttpCookie.splitMultiCookies("your_cookie_name={"key":"value","key2":"value2"}; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly").
```

But this results in a list of 2 cookies:

[image]

Then it will try to parse each cookie and it fails on the second since it does not contain an `=` sign:

```
3. HttpCookie.parseInternal(""key2":"value2"}; Max-Age=3600; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly")
```

[image]

But I actually can not believe it can't parse cookies that contain JSON. Can you help me? Is there a setting or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cookie value does not conform to the official cookie syntax.  [RFC 6256](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) states that a cookie-value consists of

```
*cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
```

where `cookie-octet` is:

```
US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs, whitespace, DQUOTE, comma,
semicolon, and backslash
```

and CTLs refers to ASCII control characters, and `DQUOTE` is the ASCII double quote character (`"`).

Your JSON contains double quotes and commas.  That causes the cookie to be rejected by the `parse` method.

If you want to pass arbitrary JSON in cookies, then you need to do something to "hide" any characters that are not allowed:

- If the JSON is encoded as ASCII, you could use percent encoding or base64 encoding.
- If the JSON is encoded in UTF8, then base64 is the advisable.

Also, beware that there can be limits on the size of a cookie (including name, value and attributes.)